# Elasticsearch index with synonym, stopwords filter not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the following index in which I am using stopwords, synonyms, and lowercase filters in an analyzer, then I am using it in field test_field.

```
{
"mappings": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "test_field": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "synonym_words_analyzer"
        }
        
      }
},
"settings": {
      "index": {
        "routing": {
          "allocation": {
            "include": {
              "_tier_preference": "data_content"
            }
          }
        },
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "english_stopwords": {
            "type":"stop",
            "language":"english",
            "stopwords":["a","an","and","are","as","at","be","but","by","for","if","in","into","is","it","no","not",
              "of","on","or","such","that","the","their","then","there","these","they",
              "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"]
            },
            "english_synonyms": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "lenient": true,
              "synonyms": ["International Cricket Council => ICC, I.C.C"]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "synonym_words_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "english_synonyms",
                "english_stopwords"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "0"
      }
    }
}
```

Then I indexed the following data

```
{
  "test_field": "International Cricket Council vs bcci"
}
POST wordforms_example/_doc
{
  "test_field": "I.C.C vs bcci"
}
POST /wordforms_example/_doc
{
  "test_field": "ICC vs bcci"
}
```

Then I executed a match_phrase query

```
{
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "highlight":{
      "require_field_match":true,
      "fields":{
         "*":{
            
         }
      },
      "pre_tags":[
         "<b>"
      ],
      "post_tags":[
         "</b>"
      ]
   },
   "timeout":"5s",
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match_phrase":{
                  "test_field":{
                     "query":"icc"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":100,
   "sort":{
      "_score":"desc"
   }
}
```

I got the result as expected as follows

```
      {
        "_index": "wordforms_example",
        "_id": "PVb4VIMBajDdOcAZZ2om",
        "_score": 0.3788134,
        "_source": {
          "test_field": "International Cricket Council vs et"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "test_field": [
            "<b>International Cricket Council</b> vs et"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "wordforms_example",
        "_id": "Plb5VIMBajDdOcAZA2o9",
        "_score": 0.3788134,
        "_source": {
          "test_field": "International Cricket Council vs bcci"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "test_field": [
            "<b>International Cricket Council</b> vs bcci"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "wordforms_example",
        "_id": "QFb5VIMBajDdOcAZZ2qA",
        "_score": 0.3788134,
        "_source": {
          "test_field": "ICC vs bcci"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "test_field": [
            "<b>ICC</b> vs bcci"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

but when I do match query as follows it doesn't give any result

```
{
   "track_total_hits":true,
   "highlight":{
      "require_field_match":true,
      "fields":{
         "*":{
            
         }
      },
      "pre_tags":[
         "<b>"
      ],
      "post_tags":[
         "</b>"
      ]
   },
   "timeout":"5s",
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "test_field":{
                    "query": "international"
                  }
                 }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                 "test_field":{
                    "query": "Cricket"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                 "test_field":{
                    "query": "Council"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":100,
   "sort":{
      "_score":"desc"
   }
}
```

But instead of giving synonyms as **["International Cricket Council => ICC, I.C.C"]**,
If I give as follows,
**["International Cricket Council, ICC, I.C.C => International Cricket Council, ICC, I.C.C"]**

As a result unnecessary highlighting and all hapening.For all the above queries.Sample result:

```
     {
       "_index": "wordforms_example",
       "_id": "QlYFVYMBajDdOcAZjGqs",
       "_score": 1.1955718,
       "_source": {
         "test_field": "I.C.C vs bcci"
       },
       "highlight": {
         "test_field": [
           "<b>I.C.C</b> <b>vs</b> <b>bcci</b>"
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "_index": "wordforms_example",
       "_id": "Q1YFVYMBajDdOcAZlGq8",
       "_score": 1.1955718,
       "_source": {
         "test_field": "ICC vs bcci"
       },
       "highlight": {
         "test_field": [
           "<b>ICC</b> <b>vs</b> <b>bcci</b>"
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       "_index": "wordforms_example",
       "_id": "QVYFVYMBajDdOcAZhWpI",
       "_score": 1.1175997,
       "_source": {
         "test_field": "International Cricket Council vs bcci"
       },
       "highlight": {
         "test_field": [
           "<b>International Cricket</b> <b>Council</b> vs bcci"
         ]
       }
     }
   ]
```

And when there is a massive amount of data, and if we do a match search for **International Cricket Council** there will be a count mismatch in results.
Anyone know why this is happening. Thank you

Comment: Hi everyone, anyone knows a solution for this synonym issue? I am facing a lot of issues while using synonyms or synonym_graph.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using the synonym at index time, and at the time of indexing the document will have its terms expanded to the other synonyms but as you use the substitution rule "=>" you change "International Cricket Council" to ICC , ICC.

Run this and look at the generated tokens:

```
GET test_index/_analyze
{
   "text": [
     "International Cricket Council vs bcci"
   ],
   "analyzer": "synonym_words_analyzer"
}
```

If you change the synonyms like this:

```
"synonyms": [
               "International Cricket Council => ICC, I.C.C, International Cricket Council"
             ]
```

You will get a result similar to this:

```
   "_source" : {
           "test_field" : "International Cricket Council vs bcci"
         },
         "highlight" : {
           "test_field" : [
             "<b>International</b> <b>Cricket</b> <b>Council</b> vs bcci"
           ]
         }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you @rabbitbr So you are suggesting using search_analyzer?

Comment: I believe it will not get the results you need.  Using "International Cricket Council => ICC, I.C.C, International Cricket Council" you will get the international cricket council tokens, doesn't that solve it?

Comment: i was able to produce the token before also, and the tokens were valid too. Update synonym to "International Cricket Council => ICC, I.C.C, International Cricket Council"  and tried but it was not returning all the valid docs for the above queries(which I have mentioned in my question)

Comment: The first or second query not return valid docs? The first will not be impacted by this change. The second has the must with 3 match, it will return only 1 doc. (I'm using the example docs you left in the post.)

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Both of the queries didn't return three documents. When I searched for ```icc``` with the match query, it returned only 2 docs. IN match_phrase query it returned only 1 docs